# Put hive shell commands in python script

Tags: python, shell, apache-spark, unix, hive

I have a .py script and I want to add hive shell commands in the script when submitted with spark-submit.

Simply the .py script would have:

```
hive -e "show create table my_table.table1"
```

When I use spark-submit [my_file] it gives the following error:

```
  hive -e "show create table my_table.table1"
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
19/08/05 10:46:37 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/08/05 10:46:37 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-343fcf03-67e6-443c-80c8-cf1786d85017
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: If you want to execute these using python.. use python subprocess module

Comment: See below for 
reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212849/failed-parseexception-line-121-cannot-recognize-input-near-eof-eof-e/57214452#57214452